# Dax formula to calculate cumulative students

Tags: powerpivot, dax, ssas-2012

I am building first cube in SSAS 2012 Tabular modeling. I got one fact table contains following columns

TermDate     StudentKey          PaperKey       marks                CumulativeNoOfStudents

20100601     1                   1               70                   2

20100601     2                   1               70                   2

20100601     3                   1               69                   3

20100601     4                   **2**           68                   1

Now i need to generate Cumulative Number Of Students (5th column) as an output (calculated column) against each row using DAX.

Can someone help me to build the DAX formula please.

Comment: can you define the cumulative number of students column in more detail?  Is it the number of distinct students that made the same marks on the same paper (PaperKey) on the same date (TermDate)?

Answer (score 3):

On the basis that your StudentKey is numeric, sequential and unique you can use the following:

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table), FILTER(Table,Table[StudentKey]<=EARLIER(Table[StudentKey]))
```

Assuming your table is called 'Table'

HTH
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

on the basis of some assumption like studentkey is numeric and your date table is DimDate with date as unique column, and fact table name as FactStudent  can use the below formula also.

Cumalative No of Students :=CALCULATE (CountRows(FactStudent), FILTER(ALL(DimDate[Date]), DimDate[Date] <= MAX(DimDate[Date])))